Timer triggered Azure Durable function not working in App Plan
I have a timer-triggered durable Azure function mentioned by Ikhtesam Afrin in this post.
I had it in the consumption plan and it was working fine.
I have deployed it in the App plan (B3).
On the home page of the durable function, I can see all my 3 functions listed, including the Activity function.
Upon execution, I do not see any call to the Activity function, though the Orchestrator function is getting triggered. There are no exceptions.
Where should I look?

Check the invocation logs in Activity function.

Configure Application Insights and check the logs under Monitoring=>Log Stream=>Application Logs.
I have deployed the same function code to Function app with App Service Plan(B3).
Code Snippet:
[Function(nameof(Function1))]
public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
   [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
    logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
    var outputs = new List<string>();

    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));

    return outputs;
}

[Function(nameof(SayHello))]
public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
    logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
    return $"Hello {name}!";
}

[Function("Function1_TimerStart")]
public static async Task TimerStart(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_TimerStart");

    string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
        nameof(Function1));

    logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}' via TimerTrigger.", instanceId);
}

Portal:

Able to run all the functions as expected.
Application logs:
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1_TimerStart' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-10-28T09:25:00.0121323+00:00', Id=f5a77596-584a-4c67-b4c4-10c51674ba95)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Scheduling new Function1 orchestration with instance ID 'eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226' and 0 bytes of input data.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'Function1 (Orchestrator)' scheduled. Reason: NewInstance. IsReplay: False. State: Scheduled. RuntimeStatus: Pending. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 99.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'Function1 (Orchestrator)' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (Redacted 0 characters). State: Started. RuntimeStatus: Running. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 100. TaskEventId: -1
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=3a741647-d393-40ca-b37f-bbf4d2b92794)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Saying hello.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=3a741647-d393-40ca-b37f-bbf4d2b92794, Duration=12ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Started orchestration with ID = 'eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226' via TimerTrigger.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'Function1 (Orchestrator)' awaited. IsReplay: False. State: Awaited. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 101.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1_TimerStart' (Succeeded, Id=f5a77596-584a-4c67-b4c4-10c51674ba95, Duration=113ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'SayHello (Activity)' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (Redacted 9 characters). State: Started. RuntimeStatus: Running. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 102. TaskEventId: 0
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.SayHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=86202cba-f190-4ea1-ab15-6a6f727bfb51)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Saying hello to Tokyo.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.SayHello' (Succeeded, Id=86202cba-f190-4ea1-ab15-6a6f727bfb51, Duration=1ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'SayHello (Activity)' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (Redacted 14 characters). State: Completed. RuntimeStatus: Completed. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 103. TaskEventId: 0
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=ecfd424d-80ce-4a03-b836-c16e13e3efcf)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=ecfd424d-80ce-4a03-b836-c16e13e3efcf, Duration=2ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'Function1 (Orchestrator)' awaited. IsReplay: False. State: Awaited. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 104.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'SayHello (Activity)' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (Redacted 11 characters). State: Started. RuntimeStatus: Running. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 105. TaskEventId: 1
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.SayHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=43efd269-a3ea-45b6-8469-d16b8390253d)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Saying hello to Seattle.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.SayHello' (Succeeded, Id=43efd269-a3ea-45b6-8469-d16b8390253d, Duration=1ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'SayHello (Activity)' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (Redacted 16 characters). State: Completed. RuntimeStatus: Completed. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 106. TaskEventId: 1
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=4f371c69-d41d-485e-8d7d-a824eb58c697)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=4f371c69-d41d-485e-8d7d-a824eb58c697, Duration=1ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'Function1 (Orchestrator)' awaited. IsReplay: False. State: Awaited. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 107.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'SayHello (Activity)' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (Redacted 10 characters). State: Started. RuntimeStatus: Running. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 108. TaskEventId: 2
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.SayHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=d7fea55b-9cce-443c-8cad-e574c22f5d94)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Saying hello to London.
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.SayHello' (Succeeded, Id=d7fea55b-9cce-443c-8cad-e574c22f5d94, Duration=1ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'SayHello (Activity)' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (Redacted 15 characters). State: Completed. RuntimeStatus: Completed. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 109. TaskEventId: 2
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=deb17307-5323-49ab-9c0b-80ec2e7567a1)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=deb17307-5323-49ab-9c0b-80ec2e7567a1, Duration=2ms)
2024-10-28T09:25:00Z   [Information]   eb99bcb3dcf143a39b5406cbbe102226: Function 'Function1 (Orchestrator)' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (Redacted 49 characters). State: Completed. RuntimeStatus: Completed. HubName: kpapp28. AppName: kpapp28. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNumber: 110. TaskEventId: -1

Activity function:

